# Python GoogleDocs API How can I copy & paste element with formatting into other element?

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I have a GoogleDoc file that has tables of two cells. I need to get the data from the second cell along with the formatting and paste it into a new table at the beginning of the document.

Using the `documents.get` method, I learned how to retrieve data and find the desired data in the JSON response. But on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request) site I still couldn't find how to insert text with formatting.

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I added an image for clarification

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your provided image, I could not understand the logic for achieving your expected result. In your situation, do you want to copy a table of "2024.01.01 My Table 1" to the top of a different document as "2024.01.02 My Table 2"?

Comment: By the way, can you provide your current script?